# Searchlogic OR condition results in undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something since this is my first time using Searchlogic.

Whenever I use a statement like `Listing.city_like_or_state_like(params[:search])` in my controller, Rails returns an "Undefined Method" error. I'm trying to search 2 fields within the same model.

However, if I use `Listing.city_like(params[:search])` everything is totally fine.

Am I missing something here? I thought OR conditions could be chained together with Searchlogic. How can I implement an OR statement?

Answer (score 1):

Searchlogic only supports one "operator" per call. So what you want to do is

```
Listing.city_or_state_like(params[:search])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use named_scopes and pass the params straight to SearchLogic

**models/listing.rb**

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    named_scope :city_or_state_like, lambda{|*args| {
                 :conditions => ["city ILIKE ? OR state ILIKE ?", args[0], args[1] ]
                  }
                }

end
```

**controllers/listing_controller.rb**

```
#params for [:search][:city_or_state_like] = [city_var][state_var]
    Listing.search(params[:search])
```

I'm up-voting aNoble's answer though :D