# Searchlogic: how do I define a namedscope so that I can use OR on an associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

So, I found this: [Searchlogic OR condition results in undefined method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877439/searchlogic-or-condition-results-in-undefined-method)

But that only works for fields on the model your are searching on directly.
I have a suscription model, but I want to search over the different subscriptions' account names OR their other_field, for example.

from the above link (and modified) I'd like to be able to do something similar to this:

```
  named_scope :account_name_full_domain_like, lambda{ |name|{
     :conditions => ["accounts.name LIKE ? OR accounts.full_domain LIKE ?", "%" + name + "%", "%" + name + "%"],
     :joins => "LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.id = `subscriptions`.account_id"
    }}
```

but now I get an error on this:

```
27:     <% form_for @search do |f| %>  

undefined method `subscription_subscription_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x11061dbc0>
```

EDIT:
figured it out:
had to include .search in my call for assignment of the @search var

```
@search = Subscription.search.account_name_full_domain_like(term)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your named scope is on your Subscription model, you will be returning subscription records. Your condition and join seem to be valid. I am not sure what the relationship of this named scope is to the instance variable @search you seem to be using in your view.

Is the path '**subscription_subscription_path**' where you were expecting to submit this form to? If so, run "rake routes", and ensure that you have a path named 'subscription_subscription_path'.

If you want to submit to an alternate path, you can specify the url to submit to in form_for by doing something like the following:

```
<% form_for @search, :url => subscription_path(@search) %>
```

More information on specifying a URL for form_for can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Comment: I didn't know you could do that. neato.

Comment: not... specifically, but, it does solve the error, assuming everything in the controller is find and dandy. By actual problem's solution is described under the edit part of my post.